# How to convert Range<Int> to Set<Int>?

Tags: swift, set

I want to convert a `Range` of `Int` to a `Set<Int>` like this

`[0..<count]` -> `Set[1,2,3..count]`.

Comment: FYI, `0..<count` doesn't produce the sequence `1,2,3..count` and the numbers in the set are not ordered. You should use `IndexSet` if that condition is important for your logic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A (countable) range is a *sequence,* and  `Set` has an initializer

```
public init<Source : Sequence where Source.Iterator.Element == Element>(_ sequence: Source)
```

which allows to create a set from a sequence directly:

```
let count = 10
let range = 0..<count // CountableRange<Int>
let set = Set(range)  // Set<Int>
```

Or just

```
let count = 10
let set = Set(0..<count) // Set<Int>
```

Or

```
let set = Set(0..<10)  // Set<Int>
```

Note that there is also `IndexSet` which is a dedicated type
to manage sets of (non-negative) integer values:

```
let indexSet = IndexSet(0..<10)
```

Comment: The same exact answer is also applicable for Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

With Swift 5, `Set` has an initializer called [`init(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/3128843-init). `init(_:)` has the following declaration:

```
init<Source>(_ sequence: Source) where Element == Source.Element, Source : Sequence
```

> Creates a new set from a finite sequence of items.

The Playground sample code below shows how to use `init(_:)` in order to convert a range into a set:

```
let count: Int = 10
let range: Range<Int> = 0 ..< count
let set: Set<Int> = Set(range)

print(range) // prints: 0..<10
print(set) // prints: [1, 4, 0, 9, 3, 6, 5, 7, 2, 8]
```

---

As an alternative, you can convert your range into an `IndexSet` instance using one of the two following `IndexSet`'s initializers: [`init(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/indexset/3126692-init) and [`init(integersIn:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/indexset/2983369-init).

The Playground sample code below shows how to use `init(_:)` or `init(integersIn:)` in order to convert a range into a set:

```
import Foundation

let count: Int = 10
let range: Range<Int> = 0 ..< count
let indexSet: IndexSet = IndexSet(range)
//let indexSet: IndexSet = IndexSet(integersIn: range) // also works

print(range) // prints: 0..<10
print(indexSet) // prints: 10 indexes

for range in indexSet.rangeView {
    print(range) // prints: 0..<10
}
```

Comment: The declaration is slightly different but practically the `init` method does exactly the same as the initializer in Martin's answer.